# Does a Divine Soul sorcerer have access to clerics' Domain Spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, sorcerer, spellcasting, domains

Does a Divine Soul sorcerer have access to the spells that are linked to the different cleric domains, as if they were a part of the cleric spell list?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 7):

## No

Clerics have access to domains thanks to their [Divine Domain](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#DivineDomain-109) feature.

The Divine Soul Sorcerer rules state:

> When your Spellcasting feature lets you learn a sorcerer cantrip or a sorcerer spell of 1st level or higher, you can choose the new spell from the cleric spell list or the sorcerer spell list.

It doesn't say anything about cleric domains, and the Divine Soul doesn't have Divine Domain or an equivalent feature.

Answer (score 5):

## Not unless they're already on the cleric spell list.

The [Divine Soul sorcerer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#DivineSoul)'s [Divine Magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#DivineMagic-745) feature (XGtE, p. 50) says:

> Your link to the divine allows you to learn spells from the cleric class. When your Spellcasting feature lets you learn or replace a sorcerer cantrip or a sorcerer spell of 1st level or higher, **you can choose the new spell from the cleric spell list** or the sorcerer spell list. You must otherwise obey all the restrictions for selecting the spell, and it becomes a sorcerer spell for you.

Essentially, rather than being limited to only the sorcerer spell list, Divine Soul sorcerers also have the spells that are on the cleric spell list as options to choose from.

Each cleric's [Divine Domain](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#DivineDomain-109) grants them a list of Domain Spells, the description for which mentions:

> **If you have a domain spell that doesn’t appear on the cleric spell list**, the spell is nonetheless a cleric spell for you.

As a Divine Soul sorcerer, no feature grants you the benefits of any cleric domain, and thus you have no such associated domain spells. Any spell that is granted as a domain spell to clerics of that Divine Domain is *only* a cleric spell for that cleric; for anyone else, it's not a cleric spell.

For instance, a [Nature Domain cleric](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#NatureDomain) (PHB, p. 61) gets [*animal friendship*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/animal-friendship) and [*speak with animals*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/speak-with-animals) as domain spells, but these spells are not normally on the cleric spell list; thus, they are cleric spells only for Nature Domain clerics, not for Life Domain clerics or Divine Soul sorcerers or anyone else.